# Bootstrapping Chef Nodes With Custom SSL Certificate

Tags: chef-infra, knife

With our Chef installation (12.0.3), we've installed a new SSL certificate from our internal, private CA. However, once we installed the certificate, we now get the following error when attempting to bootstrap new nodes, e.g.:

```
C:\ws\devops\chef\cookbooks>knife bootstrap windows winrm WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local -N CHEF_TEST_DELETE_ME -x administrator -P password -r "recipe[test]"


WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:14+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.3 ***
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:14+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1644
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:21+00:00] INFO: Client key c:/chef/client.pem is not present - registering
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:21+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: chef.mydomain.local - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local     ================================================================================
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "CHEF_TEST_DELETE_ME"
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local     ================================================================================
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:21+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local [2015-02-11T17:45:21+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `run_id' for nil:NilClass
ERROR: Failed to execute command on WIN-e9073a7mffd.mydomain.local return code 1
```

If I manually add the certificate for our CA to the `/opscode/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` file, then the server will allow subsequent bootstrap attempts.

Any ideas on how to fix this so that nodes are properly bootstrapped on the first attempt?

Answer (score 0):

To fix that you have some options.

- Add your CA cert to trusted_certs directory (see [this doc](http://docs.chef.io/knife_ssl_check.html))
- Set `ssl_verify_mode` to `:verify_none`in your knife.rb (for the first run to success as the client.rb should be done from it) and then distribute an updated `cacert.pem` and manage target `client.rb` with chef itslef (chef_client cookbook has recipes for this)

Comment: I have the certificate file for both the CA and the Chef server placed in my workstation's trusted_certs directory, but these certificates don't get copied over to the client when I bootstrap. I will try setting the ssl_verify_mode to see if this will resolve the issue, but to be honest it seems more of a hack since the mode has to be set on every workstation. I'd prefer a one-time fix if possible.

Comment: To be clear, even copying the files manually to the client don't work. If I do a 'knife ssl fetch https://chef.mydomain.local' and also manually install the CA certificate, then subsequent runs of 'knife ssl check https://chef.mydomain.local' pass. However, the bootstrap command from from workstation still fails with 'ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: chef.mydomain.local - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed' I'll add a ticket to GitHub per your suggestion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had this problem and sticked to my first option, distribution of a new cacert.pem including the ca

Comment: I have the same issue. Any updates on this? Can you give me the link of the GitHub ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the time sync between node and Chef Server? SSL expects the clocks to be pretty close and a resulting error might look the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both the client and Chef server are using the same internal NTP server and have the same date/time. I'm fairly confident at this point that it is a bug in how the 12.0.3 chef clients handle private CAs and copying the trusted_certs. I changed the server name so I could use a wildcard certificate issued by Thawte, and the problem went away.